# IE, Ext.TabPanel, and iFrame

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, extjs, tabpanel

**Here is the case:**
I have a page with an `iFrame` whose `src` points to another `aspx` page(same domain). The page the `iFrame` points to loads scripts that render `Ext.TabPanel` with some tabs in it. So, the first time the page is loaded, these components render well, nice and simple. But, the issue is when any of the tabs on the `TabPanel` are activated through a JavaScript event or a manual click, the whole `iFrame` region goes blank. I see appropriate requests (for activate event) being issued to the server and coming back with appropriate responses. It is just that the UI goes away and I don't see a thing in the `iFrame` at all, it's all blank. The strange thing is, open up the Developer Tool and make any change on any part of any associated CSS, boom, the things come back on. The other strange thing yet is that this only occurs in IE. In FF, every thing works as a charm. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an IFrame?  You should design your page to leverage the Layout Managers.  It sounds like you can achieve what you want by using the Viewport object.  In place of your IFrame, you can use a panel in the "west" region and use the AJAX calls to update/render your "center" region.

Comment: The actual page that the TabPanel is on uses exactly the same design as you suggested. I have Viewport, panels, grids, charts, and other ext components. But the IFrame is a control in another page which I use to load the actual page.

Comment: Well, this thing is taking me by surprise! So frustrated by the fact that any work-around that I was able to dig out from the web didn't quiet come to the rescue, I decided to take my last shot. And that was adding a `[viewport object].doLayout()` or `[viewport object].show()` inside the handler for the tab activate event. And guess what, that worked. Have no idea why FF didn't want that to work properly while IE did.

Comment: I think that's how I fixed it in the past as well.  Just be careful that you do not nest the doLayout call and start looping and calling it over and over.  I think you will find that it needs to be run either on the outer-most container(viewport) or from the specific panel that is not rendering.

I don't have the source from that project.  It might depend on how you have the delayedRender setting on the TabPanl too.

Comment: Ohhh, this is crazy. Now, it's not just activate event, but any thing that renders a panel, a popup or any component is having the same issue. `DateFields`(`DatePicker` to be more specific), the dropdown list of `ComboBoxs`, etc.. They all drive the entire `iFrame` to go blank. And this happens only in IE.

Comment: If it's an actual bug, you might want to submit some test HTML and script for them.  Seriously... With ajax, you don' really need to use IFrames dude.  Read up on cross-site scripting.